# Which is best pass setState or return the state value from a custom hook (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm wondering which of these two approaches is best for handling state when using custom hooks in react.

Having read [this article](https://charles-stover.medium.com/writing-testable-react-components-with-hooks-23441ee582d5) on writing testable react hooks I've started having a custom hook associated with a component to act as a single entry point for the state and business logic.

However, it has made me wonder which approach is best for handling state. Should I keep lots of state values and pass the setState action to other custom hooks or should I return a value and let the more specific hook handle the more specific state? I've made a basic example to illustrate what I'm trying to articulate!

```
// useMyComponent.ts

// Approach 1

export default (): {
  foo: string;
} => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState < string | undefined>();

  // State contained within this custom hook
  const [authorisedInfo, setAuthorisedInfo] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [googleToken, setGoogleToken] = useState<string | undefined>();
  useEffect(() => {
    // setState passed down and set within a different custom hook
    useSignInWithGoogle(setGoogleToken);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!googleToken) return;
    usePerformAuthCall(setAuthorisedInfo);
  }, [googleToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authorisedInfo || !googleToken) return;
    const { foo } = doSomethingHere(authorisedInfo, googleToken);
    setFoo(foo);
  }, [authorisedInfo, googleToken]);

  return { foo };
};

// Approach 2

export default (): {
  foo: string;
} => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState < string | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    // state value passed back from the custom hook
    const { googleToken } = useSignInWithGoogle();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!googleToken) return;
    const { authorisedInfo } = usePerformAuthCall(setAuthorisedInfo);
  }, [googleToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authorisedInfo || !googleToken) return;
    const { foo } = doSomethingHere(authorisedInfo, googleToken);
    setFoo(foo);
  }, [authorisedInfo, googleToken]);

  return { foo };
};
```

Thanks for the help!